# AppSheets timestamps and duration difference

Tags: timestamp, formula, duration, date-difference, google-appsheet

I'm build an Appsheet in a form format, currently with 39 virtual columns, where Column 3 is called "FormStart", and Columns 22,25,28 and 31 are called "TimeStamp1",2,3 and 4 respectively, and the column 33 called "Form End". and where from column 34 to 39 i tried to calculate the duration difference between steps.

The end goal is that every timestamp register the time of the moment the "next" button was pushed in the previous step, and ultimately that the difference between them gets calculated (dif between Timestamp1- FormStart; TimeStamp2- Timstamp1, etc).

This can happen in the Timestamp column or in a new column entirely, as long as I have the duration in between steps.

I tried to fill in both the formula box, and separately in the initial value box the funtion "Now()" for the form start, form end and all the timestamp columns. but I only retrieved the same value of "formstart".

I tried creating a separate action for all the steps, where all my actions are set up in this fashion:

Action "Time Dif 1-FormStart"

Data: Set the values of some columns in this row

Set these columns: TimeStamp1 ; =Now()
Time Dif 1-FormStart ; = ([TimeStamp1] - "00:00:00") - ([FormStart] - "00:00:00")

The rest is on default settings.

I have the same settings for the Action  "Time Dif 2-1", "Time Dif 3-2",  "Time Dif 4-3", "Time Dif Form End-4" and,  "Total duration" and of of course the formula presented above with their respective columns.

I then created in views> primary navigation a view for each step. but the end result I got is only the "total duration" (the last one) is retrieving an actual result...

is there any way to make this work, they way I intend?